# Subclassing with custom initializer from .sks file

Tags: sprite-kit, initialization

I have a custom class and I create nodes in the .sks file that I want to be instances of that custom class using a custom initializer.

custom class:

```
Class Enemy: SKSPritenode {
    init(name: String, image: String, health: Int) {
      // stuff here
    }
}
```

SKScene:

```
 // error at runtime:
var enemy1 = childNodeWithName("Enemy1") as! Enemy  

 // error: 
var enemy1 = childNodeWithName("Enemy1") as! Enemy(name: "enemy1, image: "enemy1", health: 100)
```

Is there a way to use the custom initializer with the .sks file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Associating your Custom Class to a Node

If you want to associate a node you create into your SKS file to a custom class, you need to:

1. Add an empty node into your SKS file
2. Select the Node
3. Open the *Custom Class inspector* in Xcode
4. Type the name of your class into the Custom Class field
5. Type the name of your project into the Module field

[image]

### Using the right initializer

When SpriteKit does load the SKS file and start building the objects to populate the scene it does not call you custom initializer but this one

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

so your Enemy class should be defined like this

```
class Enemy: SKSpriteNode {
    let health: Int

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.health = 10

        let texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Spaceship")
        super.init(texture: texture, color: .clearColor(), size: texture.size())
    }
}
```

### Test

You can now test that you have a real Enemy object into your scene defining this method into your GameScene

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let enemy = (children.filter { $0 is Enemy }).first else { fatalError("No Enemy found") }
    print(enemy)
}
```

### Using your custom initializer

Right now there is no way of passing parameter from the SKS file to your custom initializer.

However such a technique was available into CocosBuilder, an old Game Level editor available for Cocos2d so I believe sometime in the future we will be able to pass parameters from the SKS file to our custom classes.

Maybe this will be announced with the next version of SpriteKit in a few days during the WWDC 2016.

Comment: So, the short answer is that it's not yet supported, thanks.

Comment: You can now use userData in the sks file for the sprite in order to pass some data.